# Жизнь и здоровье: наша или наши?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Фраза такая: "Наша(и) жизнь и здоровье во многом зависит (-ят) от этого". Как тут правильнее сказать/написать: "наша" или "наши"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что вполне корректно будет звучать такое высказывание: Наша жизнь и здоровье зависят от этого. Местоимение НАША во множественном числе здесь как-то не звучит. 
**Нашла статью об этом. Цитирую:**
Определение, относящееся к двум или нескольким существительным – однородным членам, ***ставится в форме единственного числа:***
1)      ***если по смыслу сочетания ясно, что определение относится не только к ближайшему существительному, но и к последующим,*** например: ***российская печать, радио и телевидение; развитие нашей техники, науки и культуры; создание новой оперы, балета, музыкальной комедии; литературный карьеризм и индивидуализм; школьная успеваемость и дисциплина, в своем изложении и выводах...; каждый завод и фабрика; уличный шум и грохот; летний жар и зной; морской прилив и отлив; различной формы и цвета. Ср.: необыкновенный шум и говор (Пушкин); Дикий гусь и утка прилетели первыми (Тургенев); общий веселый говор и хохот (Л. Толстой); написать свой адрес, имя, отчество (А.Н. Толстой); Ее великолепная шуба и шляпка не произвели никакого впечатления (Чехов).***[Розенталь Д.Э.](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm)
2)
Форма числа определения может зависеть от формы падежа определяемых существительных; ср.: Можно представить себе, каким громовым ударом разразилось это письмо над моим отцом и матерью (Аксаков). – Здесь жили мои отец и мать (Чехов) (в первом случае форма косвенного падежа с предлогом, во втором – форма именительною падежа). ***Там же***.

Comment: Насчет предлога и косвенного падежа - мотивировка совершенно непонятна. Я бы и там сказал "над моими".
Что касается сочетания по смыслу, то пример из Чехова тоже выглядит совсем не бесспорным. Не вижу причин считать "великолепная" относящимся к шляпке. 
И самое главное. Из текста не следует, что использование единственного числа имперавтивно или хотя бы предпочтительно. У всех приведенных примеров из классики (кроме Чехова) есть отдельная мотивация (подробнее - по необходимости). Её нет в случае с рассматриваемым примере "нашу жизнь и злоровье".

Comment: "Насчет предлога и косвенного падежа - мотивировка совершенно непонятна".
Согласна. Очень странно.

Answer (score 2):

~1. Зависят. Для постановки сказуемого в единственном числе мотивации не вижу.

~2. Наша/Наши. Вопрос в том, если между ними смысловая разница. Судя по всему - нет.
Поэтому в данном случае предпочел бы "наши". Ибо тогда оно относится и к жизни, и к здоровью.

***Наши жизнь и здоровье во многом зависят от этого.***

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, "наши", ведь мы говорим о двух предметах, то есть о множестве. 
Либо надо так: Наша жизнь и наше здоровье... Но в любом случае - завис**я**т.